# How can I store a selected value in react combobox

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I created a combobox with react. How do I assign a value selected in the combobox to a variable or can I store it? Is there any example for this?

```
const PPP1 = props => {

    return (
      <div className='padding-div'>
          <FormGroup controlId="exampleForm.SelectCustom" className='col-8'>
              <FormLabel>1- Select Sector</FormLabel>
              <FormControl as="select" custom>
                  <option> </option>
                  <option>Agriculture</option>
                  <option>Mining</option>
                  <option>Information</option>
                  <option>Finance</option>
                  <option>Real Estate</option>
                  <option>Other</option>
              </FormControl>
          </FormGroup>

      </div>
    )
}

export default PPP1
```

Comment: Please review the answers and upvote/mark them as accepted if they helped you.

Answer (score 0):

If the FormControl object is rendered into a regular `<select>` tag, you could do the following:

Declare your state:

```
state = { 
    selectedData: '',
}
```

Then implement onChange function:

```
onChange = e => {
    this.setState({ selectedData: e.target.value });
}
```

And then bind the function:

```
<FormControl as="select" custom onChange={ this.onChange} >
```

In the end, you could access the result, calling `this.state.selectedData`

Edit: I didn't notice that you use Function component, my solution is for a class component, but it could be easily translated. Please let me know if you need help doing that.

Answer (score 0):

You might considering adding `onChange` props on FormControl component. Ie on this

```
  const handleChange = (event) => {
setState({ ...state, [event.target.name]: event.target.checked });}

<FormControlLabel
            control={<Checkbox checked={gilad} onChange={handleChange} name="gilad" />}
            label="Gilad Gray"/>
```